# Junior AI / Data Science Consultant in Financial Sector

Tags: junior

I recently got offered a position as a junior AI / data scientist consultant in a consultancy company that works on projects in financial institutions (banks, asset managers, and insurance companies). The offer is very good. The company is a big company with opportunities everywhere

I am certain I will learn a lot, and will have to work hard (which I don't mind). **However, the main doubt I have is about the culture in financial institutions.** I am not certain about the **workplace** and if I will feel **'good'** there.

The job will require me to leave my friends, family, behind (I could visit them in the weekend from time to time however), so I want to be certain if this is the direction I want to take.

I really care about the "human" aspect in my job. I Like socializing and really don't like strict, impersonal, hard, result-driven environments. 
I also care about the impact I have and if I am actually having a real "meaning" for the world.

I feel, however, that the financial sector is just that. Impersonal and strict. Without a lot of touch.

Can any of you shed some light on this?

Comment: In the financial sector, your meaning to the world is likely to be negative. (But you may have good impact when spending your earned money wisely.)

Answer (score 3):

Every company is different - including those in the financial sector.

If you are going through a recruiter, you can ask them for clues about the company's culture.

When you interview, ask to meet with some of your potential peers. Talk to them about company culture, and ask probing questions about the "human" aspects that are important to you.

Comment: The problem is, it's a consultancy. So the "company culture" kind of depends on where my first (and future) projects will be. Which is still unknown.